# pydot UnicodeDecodeError при чтении файла dot

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь сконвертировать файл формата *dot* в формат *png* с помощью **pydot**, но получаю ошибку UnicodeDecodeError.

```
import codecs
import pydot
import sadisplay

from cargo.route import models

desc = sadisplay.describe(
    [getattr(models, attr) for attr in dir(models)],
    show_methods=True,
    show_properties=True,
    show_indexes=True,
)
with codecs.open('schema.dot', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(sadisplay.dot(desc))

(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('schema.dot')
graph.write_png('schema.png')
```

Ошибка возникает в строке:
`(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('schema.dot')`
Сама ошибка:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 811: character maps to <undefined>`
При этом сам файл *dot* создаётся корректно и через онлайн конвертер конвертируется нормально.
Что делаю не так?

Comment: Да, точно. Проблема в кодировке. Файл сохранён в utf-8, но pydot пытается прочитать в cp1251. Если конвертирую вручную _schema.dot_ из utf-8 в cp1251, то всё нормально - pydot считывает файл и отрабатывает `graph.write_png('schema.png')`. Но если пытаюсь задать кодировку _schema.dot_ программно `with codecs.open('schema.dot', 'w', encoding='cp1251') as f: f.write(sadisplay.dot(desc))`, то получаю такую же ошибку _UnicodeDecodeError_.

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без записи в файл. Название функции `graph_from_dot_file` как бы намекает, что можно pydot может получать данные не только из файла. И точно - есть еще функция [`graph_from_dot_data`](https://github.com/pydot/pydot/blob/48ba231b36012c5e13611807c9aac7d8ae8c15c4/pydot.py#L273). Просто передаем данные в эту функцию напрямую без промежуточной записи в файл:

```
(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(sadisplay.dot(desc))
```

**Обновление:**

Как оказалось, для метода `write_png` нужно указать кодировку:

```
graph.write_png('schema.png', encoding='utf-8')
```

Перед конвертированием данные записываются во временный файл, потом путь к нему передается во внешнюю утилиту dot. Если не указать кодировку, то при записи во временный файл будет использована кодировка по-умолчанию. Под windows это cp1251, а в ней нет некоторых символов, которые есть у вас в данных (например, `'\u2605'` - ★).

Итоговый вариант примерно такой:

```
import codecs
import pydot
import sadisplay

from cargo.route import models

desc = sadisplay.describe(
    [getattr(models, attr) for attr in dir(models)],
    show_methods=True,
    show_properties=True,
    show_indexes=True,
)

(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(sadisplay.dot(desc))
graph.write_png('schema.png', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Оба варианта выдают туже ошибку: _UnicodeEncodeError_

Comment: Так же, если вручную сконвертировать dot-файл в cp1251, но при вызове указать utf-8 `(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('schema.dot', encoding='utf-8')`, то всё отрабатывает хорошо.

Comment: @Duncan, второй вариант не может выдавать такую ошибку. Выложите куда-нибудь полный стектрейс.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program1/PythonProjects/cargo/cargo/utils/schema2.py", line 14, in <module>
    graph.write_png('schema.png')
  File "C:\Program1\PythonProjects\cargo\venv\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1734, in new_method
    encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Program1\PythonProjects\cargo\venv\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1817, in write
    s = self.create(prog, format, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Program1\PythonProjects\cargo\venv\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1894, in create

Comment: self.write(tmp_name, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Program1\PythonProjects\cargo\venv\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1815, in write
    f.write(s)
  File "C:\Program1\WPy-3661\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 621: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Duncan, обновил ответ, попробуйте теперь

Comment: P.S. при ручной перекодировке файла в cp1251 начинает работать потому что у вас теряются все звездочки и другие символы, которых нет в cp1251

Comment: Так тоже пробовал `(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(sadisplay.dot(desc))
graph.write_png('schema.png', encoding='utf-8')` Выдает ошибку, но другую. _AssertionError: 3221225477_

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program1/PythonProjects/cargo/cargo/utils/schema2.py", line 28, in <module>
"dot" with args ['-Tpng', 'C:\\Users\\AAE53~1.LIK\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0cqpuslc'] returned code: 3221225477
    graph.write_png('schema.png', encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Program1\PythonProjects\cargo\venv\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1734, in new_method

stdout, stderr:
 b''
    encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Program1\PythonProjects\cargo\venv\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1817, in write

Comment: b'\r\n(dot.exe:4988): Pango-WARNING **: couldn\'t load font "Bitstream Vera Sans Not-Rotated 8", falling back to "Sans Not-Rotated 8", expect ugly output.\r\n\r\n(dot.exe:4988): Pango-WARNING **: couldn\'t load font "Helvetica Bold Not-Rotated 8", falling back to "Sans Bold Not-Rotated 8", expect ugly output.\r\n'
    s = self.create(prog, format, encoding=encoding)

  File "C:\Program1\PythonProjects\cargo\venv\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1945, in create
    assert process.returncode == 0, process.returncode
AssertionError: 3221225477`

Comment: @Duncan, это предупреждение от dot, что он не нашел нужный шрифт. png в итоге должен создаться, проверьте. Если это так, просто отлавливайте AssertionError и игнорируйте.

Comment: нет, png не создаётся.

Comment: Тогда остается найти pydot.py и удалить строку `assert process.returncode == 0, process.returncode`

Comment: В моём случае думаю правильнее будет сделать промежуточную конвертацию. Юникод-символы не использую - вроде ничего не теряется.